# Group notification from another app with android 7.0

Tags: java, android, notifications

I want group notifications of app that my device installed from another app. Can I do it? My device is android 7.0
Ex: Facebook showed 3 notifications but they don't grouped. So can I group them from my app that don't create new notification

Answer (score 0):

I think , You can only read another app Notifications. **Can't modify** it. But you can delete it.

Only `system privileged app` or the app which posted the notification has the permission to modify it.

But from api 24,There is a method to override the group key,

```
  sbn.setOverrideGroupKey("key");
```

You can implement [Notification Listener Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) and try overriding.

And if you want to do it for your own app, use **setGroup()**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builderOne = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    // Other properties
    .setGroupSummary(true)
    .setGroup(KEY_NOTIFICATION_GROUP);

NotificationCompat.Builder builderTwo = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    // Other properties
    .setGroupSummary(true)
    .setGroup(KEY_NOTIFICATION_GROUP);

NotificationCompat.Builder builderThree = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    // Other properties
    .setGroupSummary(true)
    .setGroup(KEY_NOTIFICATION_GROUP);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll check it